# Why does this async function expect a return value

Tags: c#, async-await, return

I have a function as follows:

```
public static async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do something that takes a long time
        bool success = ALongFunction();
        return success;
    });
}
```

The above code does not compile as it expects a return value after the await.  Why is this?  The code in the task returns a value on all execution paths and I thought that the returning of this after the await should be handled by the await mechanism.  What should I return in the above?  Do I have to do something like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> WriteMonitor(string filename, IMonitorAsync monitorAsync)
{
    bool success = false;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //do something that takes a long time
        success = ALongFunction();
    });
    return success;
}
```

The above does compile, but I was expecting the top code to compile also.

Comment: In your first code block, the `return` statement belongs to the `Func` used by `Task.Run()`. Your outer method doesn't return anything. It's like using `break;` in a nested loop; you don't expect to break out of the outer loop, do you?

Comment: try `return await Task.Run(() =>` ;)

Comment: @Fildor obviously!  Doh.  Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as an answer.  I'm sure someone else will do this in the future...

Comment: I'd love to know why I have a downvote.  What aspect of the above question does not meet forum rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return a `bool` value while your method actually returns a `Task<bool>`.

Change the method to return the awaited `Task`.

```
return await Task.Run(...);
```

Comment: Your code is correct but your first sentence is wrong; that's not the reason for the error. Because the method is marked with the `async` modifier, you actually _need to_ return a `bool` from inside the method (which gets wrapped in a `Task<bool>`). The reason for the compiler error is that the method is _not_ returning anything at all. Read my comment to the question above for more.

Comment: Actually, your description of what should happen (the second sentence) is also wrong. You are not returning a task; you are returning the `bool` value returned by the awaited task. So, you're still returning a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

In the current form the function returns a task only (not `Task<bool>`).

```
public static async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return AFunctionThatTakesALongTime();
    });
}
```

is equivalent to the following snippet:

```
public static async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    bool r = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return AFunctionThatTakesALongTime();
    });
    // not returning r
}
```

## Solution

```
return await Task.Run(() => ...)
```

Comment: "The return value of your function is `Task<bool>` so you must return `Task<bool>`." - that's not strictly true. Since the function is marked `async` then it must return a `bool` inside the method. Code calling the function will see it as a `Task<bool>`, but internally it is just returning a `bool`.

Comment: @enigmativity I disagree with your interpretation of what I wrote, but removed the statement.

Comment: In what way do you disagree?

Comment: A method with the return type of `Task<bool>` and marked with `async` returns a `Task<bool>` but it contains return statement(s) in which the operand has type `bool`.

Comment: Also, '*returns a Task<TResult>*' is the language used throughout Microsoft Docs when talking about methods like this one.

Comment: I agree with both of those statements, Your first one is exactly what I said.